# Footer view in emails

Tags: marketing-cloud

I see that many companies which use Salesforce has "This email was sent to: @emailaddress".

Is it obligatory to add it in the footer of all commercial emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not obligatory, but it is seen as helpful (both for a recipient and a marketing trying to diagnose any issues with email sends).